# wrong print in coding c using pointer and array without no warning

Tags: arrays, pointers

```
int main()
{
    int i, Quant, *Qsize1[4];
    char *size1[4], size[5];
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("Select Size : (S, M, L, XL) ");
        scanf("%s",size);
        size1[i]=size;

        printf("How much quantity for this size? : ");
        scanf("%d",Quant);
        Qsize1[i]=Quant;
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nSize %s : %d",size1[i], Qsize1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example of print that i want is = Size L : 25
but when i print the it will print the last size i enter.
also the quantity of that size is wrong.

Comment: `scanf("%s",size);` ?

Comment: why with that ?

Comment: `scanf("%c",size);` and size is an array of `char` not char.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 0):

1. All the sizes are the same when you print them because you're reading all of them to the same character array named `size`. Each iteration overrides the previous `size`, and then you end up with `size1[0]`, `size1[1]`, `size1[2]` all point to the last `size`.
2. Quantity is wrong because you should pass `scanf` the address of the integer: `scanf("%d", &Quant);`

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you should fix how you read `size` itself. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c) about how to do it properly.

Comment: I want to store the current value size that read from user to size1[i]. So I assume first size will be store in size[0], second will be store in size1[1], so  i assume it will store in different array

Comment: `size1` is an array of **pointers**. So you store in its indices **pointers** or **addresses**. In the 1st iteration, you store in `size1[0]` the **address** of `size`. In the 2nd iteration, you store in `size1[1]` the **address** of `size`. In the 3rd iteration, you store in `size1[2]` the **address** of `size`. Therefore, all the elements of the array `size1` are similar, same address. An address can only have one value stored in, and it will be the *last* value stored, in the last iteration. Understand now?

Comment: i got right print for Qsize[i], but not for size1[i], the difference between them is Qsize[i] is integer, while size[i] is string.

Comment: You can fix it few ways. I'd change the type of `size1` to `char size1[4][5]` (the `5` is because that's the size of `size`) and then instead of `size1[i]=size;` I would go `strncpy(size1[i], size, sizeof(size));`. This way you *copy* (unlike pointer which just points) the content of `size` into `size1[i]`.

Comment: really thanks lot to you. I finally got it. It really a big help for me since this is for my final project